# Why "buenas noches" when it's only one night?

Tags: etimología, saludos, plurales

Why do we say *buenas noches* and *buenas tardes* when they refer to only one night/afternoon?

---

¿Por qué se dice "buenas noches" y "buenas tardes" cuando se refieren solo a una noche o tarde?

Comment: why pants when it's only one?

Comment: @e-MEE It's not really the same, I think... But answering your comment, I found this: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pai1.htm

Comment: @e-MEE We say _(par de) pantalones_, trousers, and _(par de) gafas_ (glasses), as they can be seen as composed of two parts: two _perneras_ (trouser legs) and two _lentes_ (each of the glasses, pl. of lens).

Comment: I have got two Argentinian friends and they say "buen día".  To complete the answers given, please read these two (long) threads from the [Centro Virtual Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es/) that discuss this very matter: [Sobre «buenos días» y «buen día»](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=40911) and [¿Por qué no decimos ´buen día´?](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=795).    I find this remark especially interesting:  > También debemos tomar en cuenta el "plural expresivo" como en "Felices Pascuas", "saludos a...", "muchas gracias"...

Comment: @cdlvcdlv might this be influence from Italian, Neapolitan (*buongiorno, bòna jurnàta*), where the greeting is in singular?

Comment: @ukemi Spanish from Argentina is strongly influenced by big Italian migrations so I think is a sensible hypothesis. It would be interesting to look into it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the person says *buenas tardes / noches* he/she is wishing to the other person to have not only one, but a few good afternoons or good nights. But still you can use the singular like:

- tenga usted un buen día.
- ... una buena tarde para usted también.
- una buena noche de descanso.

All these point and refer to one day/afternoon/night.

There is also *Felices Fiestas* (season greetings) used in Christmas. The point is to wish the other more than one day of greetings.

You can clearly say that the common becomes a rule with this one, simply because there is no reference to a rule of why is said in that way.

Comment: Good point about "buenas tardes" and "que tenga una buena tarde". Regarding "Felices Fiestas", although I never asked the question, I always thought that was plural because it referred to Christmas, New Year's Day, and King's Day (several holidays during the same period of time). For the singular on Christmas, you don't have to be Jose Feliciano to know it's "Feliz Navidad".

Comment: This answer is wrong. It's not several days, that plural is denoting intesity. The effect of *have a **very** nice day* is absorbed in *have nice days*.

Comment: I do not agree with this answer. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 50):

### English

Unfortunately I can't give you a definitive answer yet. But I thought that not posting these two theories would've been a waste, so here they are:

1. This point is in my opinion the most accredited:

   In this question, *[In Spanish, why do they say "buenos noches"?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080526161902AAUjckd)*, the answerer says it comes from "**Buenas noches nos dé Dios**", which means "*may God give us good nights*" (for more than one person).

   I found some references which I consider to be official/trustworthy enough. The first is from [this page](http://books.google.it/books?id=BE-PaBe-vswC&lpg=PA52&dq=buenas%20noches%20nos%20de'%20Dios&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q=%22Buenas%20noches%20nos%20de'%20Dios%22&f=false) on "*Three-Cornered Hat & Captain Poison (Dual-Language)*" by Pedro Antonio de Alarcón and Stanley Appelbaum.

   I spotted the second source when I found this exact quote (i.e. "**Buenas noches nos dé Dios**") when reading the original version of [La casa de Bernarda Alba](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_casa_de_Bernarda_Alba) by Federico García Lorca. You can see [the quote in Google Books](http://alturl.com/u4gv7).

   About "*buenas tardes*" and "*buenos días*", I didn't find anything, but according to this theory, the origin might be similar or even "the same", as a derivation.
2. Another possibility comes from Latin:

   > *"The origin of the plural forms as a way of greeting has to be searched in the past. In former times, from the 10th century on, Spanish language began being developed from Latin where formality was a rule when addressing somebody. The plural form of old Spanish *vos* (plural you) when talking to more than one person seemed to demand a plural in the rest of the sentence parts: *“Buenos días guarden a vos”,* and the same with *tardes* and *noches*. Besides, the fact that in that age people did not run into each other everyday, due to the meagre communication means, wherever they met they said hello for the rest of the week with a plural form rather than a singular."* – [Source (SpanishDict Answers)](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/206196/the-reason-behind-buenos-das)

---

### Español

Desafortunadamente, todavía no puedo darte una respuesta definitiva. Pero creo que no publicar lo que encontré sería un desperdicio.

1. En mi opinión, ese es el punto más acreditado:

   En esa pregunta, *[In Spanish, why do they say "buenos noches"?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080526161902AAUjckd)*, el contestador dice que viene de **"Buenas noches nos dé Dios"**.

   Encontré otras referencias que considero bastante confiables. La primera viene de [esa página](http://books.google.it/books?id=BE-PaBe-vswC&lpg=PA52&dq=buenas%20noches%20nos%20de'%20Dios&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q=%22Buenas%20noches%20nos%20de'%20Dios%22&f=false) sobre "*Three-Cornered Hat & Captain Poison (Dual-Language)*" de Pedro Antonio de Alarcón y Stanley Appelbaum.

   La segunda la localicé gracias a esa cita (o sea "**Buenas noches nos dé Dios**") que encontré leyendo la versión original de [La casa de Bernarda Alba](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_casa_de_Bernarda_Alba) de Federico García Lorca. Puedes ver [la cita en Google Books](http://alturl.com/u4gv7).

   No puse encontrar nada de *"buenas tardes"* y *"buenos días"*, pero puede ser que la origen sea la misma o parecida.
2. Otra posibilidad viene de Latino (traducción):

   > La origin de los plurales en Español en los saludos tiene que ser buscada en el pasado. En tiempos pasados, desde el siglo X en adelante, el idioma Español empezó a desarrollarse del Latino cuando era obligatorio ser formal para dirigirse a alguien. La forma plural *vos*, del Español antiguo, parecía exigir una presencia del plural también en las otras partes de la frase: *“Buenos días guarden a vos”*, y lo mismo para *tardes* y *noches*. Además, el hecho que en esos tiempos las personas no se veían cada día, siendo los medios de comunicación insuficientes, se hubieran dado los saludos por el resto de la semana con un plural más que un singular." – [Source (SpanishDict Answers)](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/206196/the-reason-behind-buenos-das)

Comment: +1 for making the point multiple times that the info so far is not reliable.

Comment: Yahoo Answers and SpanishDict Answers are just forums -they are not reliable. But thanks for still keeping an eye on it

Comment: @Theta30 Yes, I'm well aware of it. :P But the first one was more or less confirmed since it does appear in a book (famous one) that has that situation: some people and someone wishing that for everyone.

Comment: Buenos días os de Dios. Felix, & faustum (?) lume, Iuppicer (?) pluat mel. precor, vt hic dies tibi cabdidus illuceat. Felicem tibi deprecor lucem. (1654, Bartolomé Bravo, Thesaurus Hispano latinus, vtriusque linguae diues opum). Buenos días os de Dios, labradores de mi casa (1865, Eduardo González Pedroso, Autos Sacramentales.) La definición latina no la entiendo del todo, pero es casi un rezo para que tengas buen clima para la siembra o la cosecha. Lo que antes era esencial. Quizás por esos era también "bonus dies" en latín, aunque curiosamente sólo se ha conservado en el español.

Comment: Aprovechemos la recompensa ofrecida a esta respuesta para incluir una versión en castellano :)

Comment: @fedorqui Lo siento, vi tu comentario sólo ahora. Es tarde aquí ahora, agregaré una traducción mañana. :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu traducción, Alenanno. La verdad es que no entiendo porqué la recompensa fue a parar a la otra respuesta, cuando esta tuya es la correcta. Sea como fuere, recibe un gran +1 por tu publicación.

Comment: @fedorqui Lo siento si te contesto un poco tarde, pero gracias! :)

Comment: Nunca es tarde si la dicha es buena :)

Answer (score 8):

## 1. Origin of *buenas noches*

*Buenas noches* is a contraction of the older Spanish salutations:

- *Id a buenas noches*
- *Dios os dé buenas noches*

This can be seen in the earliest recorded uses of the phrase:

> Amigos, id a buenas noches & dormid y folgad fasta mañana...
>
> - *Libro del cavallero Cifar* (1300-1305)
>
> ---
>
> E ora idvos a buenas noches...
>
> - *Crónica del rey don Rodrigo, postrimero rey de los godos*, Pedro de Corral (c.1430)
>
> ---
>
> Señor capitán, vaya vuestra merced a buenas noches, que ya es tarde. [...]
>
> Id, cavallero, a buenas noches, que mañana nos veremos.
>
> - *La corónica de Adramón*, (c.1492)

> ... dixole señor dios vos de buenas noches...
>
> - *Traduccción de Lanzarote del Lago* (c.1414)
>
> ---
>
> Dyos os dé buenas noches, que yo buenas las quiero tener.
>
> - *La corónica de Adramón*, (c.1492)
>
> ---
>
> **Eritea:** Buenas noche os dé Dios.
>
> - *Égloga de Plácida y Vitoriano*, Juan el Encina (1513)

Similar phrases are seen around the same time with *días*.

## 2. Modern salutation

From the 16th century onwards we start seeing *buenas noches/buenos días* "a secas" used as a salutation:

> **Tía:** Pues allá dejé el candil. Ve pasico, que duerme, y cierra la puerta.
>
> **Rampín:** Sí haré. Buenas noches.
>
> - *La Lozana Andaluza*, Francisco Delicado (1528)

> **MOÑIZ:** Buenos días, cavalleros.
>
> - *Comedia Seraphina [Propaladia]*, Bartolomé de Torres Naharro (1517)

## 3. *Buenas tardes*

*Buenas tardes* appears to have developed later, either as a calque of English *good evening*:

> **ALONSO:** Tratábamos de las salutaciones que se usan en Inglaterra, y de las que se usan in España.
>
> **GUILLERMO:** ¿Cuáles son mejores?
>
> **ALONSO:** Cierto, en esto adonde quiera hay abusos. Cuando dice el español "Dios os guarde", "en hora buena estéis", "Dios os dé salud", y el inglés "buenas tardes" y otras semejantes, yo apruébola por buena salutación.
>
> - *Diálogos de John Minsheu*, (1599)

or by analogy to *buenos días, buenas noches*, first appearing as *"ten buenas tardes"* in the 17th century:

> **Venus:** Cupido, ten buenas tardes;
>
> - *Mojiganga de Cupido y Venus*, Román Montero de Espinosa (1662)

With the shortened form appearing a century later:

> Y yo también voy; y pues aquí nada que hacer tengo y allá hago falta, señores, buenas tardes y hasta luego.
>
> - *El sarao*, Ramón de la Cruz (1764)

---

---

---

**Further reading:**

<sup>In particular, the *Epístolas familiares* (Fray Antonio de Guevara (1521-1543)) outlines the various greeting and farewell salutations used in Spain and neighbouring countries in the 16th century. The author gives a very amusing detail of the his opinion on the courtly greetings (which differed considerably in style from the common ones):</sup>

> <sup>Cuanto a lo que queréis saber de mí, es a saber, cómo se ha de saludar un hombre a otro cuando se toparen de nuevo, sé os decir que ni lo osaría aconsejar, ni menos determinar, porque esto no se alcança por escritura, sino que se ha de ver la costumbre de la tierra. Dexados aparte los principios por se notos y las máximas naturales en filosofía, así como es "per quod unumquodque tale et illud magis", y aquella que dice "si ab equalibus equalia demas, que remanent sunt equalia", y aquella que dice "omnis triangulis habet tres angulos equales duobus rectis", y aquella que dice "finitum tandem per ablationem consumitur", en todas las otras costumbres morales y rurales hemos de estar a lo que el vulgo hace y a lo que la costumbre quiere. **Por haceros placer y en algo satisfacer, lo que yo haré será relataros aquí lo que en este caso los siglos pasados hicieron, y lo que en nuestros tiempos se hace, con protestación que vuestra Señoría elixa, no lo que yo le dixere, sino lo que a él le paresciere y por bien tuviere.**</sup>
>
> <sup>Los idumeos, cuando se topaban, decían estas palabras: "Dominus vobiscum", que quiere decir: "el Señor sea con vosotros".</sup>
>   <sup>Los verdaderos hebreos, cuando se saludaban, decían: "Ave, mi frater", como si dixese: "Dios te dé salve, hermano mío."</sup>
>   <sup>Los filósofos griegos, cuando se saludaban, decían: "Avete omnes", como si dixera: "estéis todos enhorabuena".</sup>
>   <sup>Los thebanos, cuando se saludaban, decían: "Salus sit vobis", como si dixeran: "Dios os dé salud".</sup>
>   <sup>Los antiguos romanos, cuando se saludaban, decían: "Salus sit vobis", como si dixeran: "Dios os dé buen hado".</sup>
>   <sup>Los sículos, que son los de Sicilia, cuando se saludaban, decían: "Diu vo guarde", que es a saber, "Dios os guarde".</sup>
>   <sup>Los cartagineses no se saludaban aunque se topaban, sino que en señal de amistad se tocaban las manos derechas el uno al otro y se las besaban.</sup>
>   <sup>Los moros tampoco se saludaban, aunque se topaban, sino que al tiempo de verse se besan los hombros, y al despedir se besan en las rodillas.</sup>
>
> <sup>**En Italia** es costumbre que en un solo día se saludan de tres maneras, a saber: que a la mañana dicen en cuanto se topan: "Bon matin", que quiere decir que le dé Dios buena mañana. Después de comer, si se topan, se dicen: "Bon jor", que quiere decir que le dé Dios buenos dias. [fol. 14] **Ya que quiere anochecer y encender candelas, dicen "Bon vespre", que quiere decir que les dé Dios buenas noches.** También es costumbre entre los Ítalos que cuando se apartan unos de otros dicen: "Me recomendo", que quiere decir yo me encomiendo en vuestra merced.</sup>
>   <sup>En el reino de Valencia, cuando se topan, se saludan de esta manera: "Ben seao benguth, monseñor", como si dixese: "Vengáis en horabuena, señor mío", y al tiempo que se despiden dicen: "a deo riao, Perote", que quiere decir: "quedaos a Dios, Pedro". Al cual le replica el otro: "Anao en bo hora", como si dixese: "Andad en horabuena".</sup>
>   <sup>En Cataluña, cuando topan con alguno, le saludan de esta manera: "Ben seao arribath", como si dixesen: "Bien seáis arribado a la tierra".</sup>
>
> <sup>**Acá, en esta nuestra Castilla, es cosa de espantar, y aun para se reír, las maneras y diversidades que tienen en se saludar, así cuando se topan como cuando se despiden, y aun cuando se llaman. Unos dicen "Dios mantenga"; otros dicen "manténgaos Dios"; otros, "enhorabuena estéis", y otros, "enhorabuena vais"; otros, "Dios os guarde"; otros, "Dios sea con vos"; otros, "quedaos a Dios"; otros, "vais con Dios"; otros, "Dios os guíe"; otros, "el ángel os acompañe"; otros, "a buenas noches"; otros, "con vuestra merced"; otros, "guarde os Dios"; otros, "a Dios, señores"; otros, "a Dios, paredes", y aún otros dicen ¿"hao quién está acá?"**</sup>
>
> <sup>**Todas estas maneras de saludar se usan solamente entre los aldeanos y plebeyos y no entre los cortesanos y hombres polidos, porque si por malos de sus pecados dixese uno a otro en la corte "Dios mantenga" o "Dios os guarde", le lastimarían en la honrra y le darían una grita. El estilo de la Corte es decirse unos a otros "beso las manos de vuestra merced", otros dicen "beso los pies a vuestra Señoría", otros dicen "yo soy siervo y esclavo perpetuo de vuestra casa".** Lo que en este caso siento es que debía ser el que esto inventó algún hombre vano y liviano, y aun mal cortesano; porque decir uno que besará las manos a otro es mucha torpedad, y decir que le besa los pies es gran suçiedad. Yo vergüença he de oír decir "bésoos las manos", y muy grande asco he de oír decir "bésoos los pies", porque con las manos limpiámonos las narices, con las manos nos limpiamos la lagaña, con la mano nos rascamos la sarna y aun nos servimos con ellas de otra cosa que no es para decir en la plaça. Cuanto a los pies, no podemos negar sino que por la mayor parte andan sudados, traen largas las uñas, están llenos de callos y andan acompañados de adrianes y aun cubiertos de polvo o cargados de lodo. Con estas tan torpes y inormes condiciones, de mí digo y por mí juro que querría más unas manos y pies de ternera comer, que los pies y manos de ningún cortesano besar.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, it's because the person saying that is wishing the other person 'continued' well-being rather than 'singular', 'one-time' well being.

Keep in mind a big part of Spanish is influenced by the slavery culture created in Latin America by the Spanish conquistadors. The serfs, the indigenous people, were expected to be 'more than courteous' to their masters, hence the abundance of courtesy in the Latin American version of Spanish as opposed to the 'original' Spanish you hear in Spain.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a difference that would indicate this 'courtesy' variation in the language?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I could answer that in 20 different angles.

Comment: I'm curious how the "original" Spanish you hear in Spain reflects courtesy.  I understand that Usted is more commonly used but are there other indicators that someone speaking Spanish from another country might not be familiar with?

Comment: Well, been to Spain a couple of times and, there seems to be no courtesy, certainly not in the entire central region. Only in Cataluña and Andalucía did I hear a rare 'please' but I could have been dreaming.

For the most part, people just say things in a dry manner, for example: 'Give me that' - 'dame eso' | 'Pasame el vaso' - 'pass me the glass'. There's no please/would/could/should/maybe or anything like that preceding the questions

Comment: @Soktra I don't agree. The courtesy expresions are often and widely used, between people that doesn't know each other. A different thing is when there's confidence - then it is like you have exposed (there's a spanish tell "donde hay confianza da asco"). But I could be wrong. I've lived here all my life long and maybe I'm so used to this supposed lack of courtesy that don't see it.

Comment: @TomasNarros Es, "donde hay confianza da asco" similar de la frase inglesa, "Familiarity breeds contempt"?

Comment: I only spoke from personal experience. Whenever I used courtesy phrases I'd get shut down and/or corrected. When I spoke roughly with 0 courtesy, everybody understood me perfectly.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the second point is relevant, since "Buenas noches/tardes/días" is used in Spain as well.

Answer (score 0):

English: It's called "plural expressive". Translated could be 'expression of plurality'. It expresses **intensity**, rather than **quantity**. So when you're using 'Buenos dias', your not trying to wish lots of good days, rather you are expressing a really, really good day (note that when Spanish people want to stress something, we repeat some words). This plural expression on greetings is quite unique for Spanish (I've read that is not of common use on other languajes). There are plenty of examples for this 'plural expressive': Buenos dias, buenas noches, felicidades, 'la mejor de las suertes', etc.

Spanish: Se llama *plural expresivo*, y denota intensidad (no asi cantidad). Entonces, cuando usas 'Buenos dias' no estas realmente deseando muchos Buenos dias a alguien. Estas deseando muy, muy buen dia. Hasta donde tengo entendido, este saludo en plural expresivo es unico en las lenguas romances, e inclusive hasta en algunas lenguas de origen anglosajon. Hay muchos ejemplos de expresiones que usan el plural expresivo: Buenos dias, buenas noches, felicidades, etc.