# Why is it that the morning greeting "buenos dias" is used in the plural?

Tags: saludos, número-gramatical

All other languages I know use a singular word for "day" or "morning" in such a greeting. The English say "good morning", the French "bonjour", the Portuguese "bom dia", Germans say "guten Tag" and Italians "buongiorno".  Why is it that the Spanish greeting "buenos días" is in the plural form?

Comment: The question applies also (actually even more) to "buenas tardes" and "buenas noches".  It has been asked here https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/513/why-buenas-noches-when-its-only-one-night

Answer (score 1):

En español existe un tipo de plural llamado "plural expresivo". Este es un plural que no denota cantidad, sino intensidad.

Dejo un link que me parecio interesante y completo con la explicacion:

[http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Buenos%20días-buenas%20tardes-noches.htm](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Buenos%20d%C3%ADas-buenas%20tardes-noches.htm)

Comment: Esta respuesta ganaría mucho si pudieses aportar alguna referencia al "plural expresivo" y algunos ejemplos adicionales para explicar el concepto en otros contextos.

Comment: Gracias Diego por la sugerencia, acabo de editar para agregar un link que me parecio muy completo.

Comment: Lo del plural expresivo explica también [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16688/12637).