# Por qué decimos "buenos días" y no "buen día"?

Tags: gramática

Why do we use plurals in these situations?

Otro ejemplo: buenas noches.

Comment: Can you give us more context of when and where these are used?

Comment: Sorry. I mean to say "good morning" and "good night" in Spanish. I just edited my question.

Comment: *decimos*, no hablamos.

Comment: Answered here https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/513/why-buenas-noches-when-its-only-one-night in the context of _buenas tardes_